# Junit test coverage is showing 0%

Tags: java, maven, junit5

I am writing test case for mapper method where new object instance is creating for mapping. How to mock all mapper objects and set in setter? Eclipse tool passing test but jacoco is giving 0% coverage on this code.

```
    public class NewUseInsideMethods {

    public StudentOldTestingReturn OldLogicTesting(StudentOldTesting Student) {

        StudentOldTestingReturn sturentReturn = new StudentOldTestingReturn();

        OldBatchName batchName = new OldBatchName();
        batchName.setId("1");
        batchName.setName("test");

        sturentReturn.setId(batchName.getId());
        sturentReturn.setName(Student.getName());

        return sturentReturn;
     }
    }
```

```
    public class OldBatchName {

    private String name;
    private String id;
    //setter and getter
    }

    public class StudentOldTesting {
    private String name;
    private String id;
    //setter and getter
    }

    public class StudentOldTestingReturn {
    private String name;
    private String id;
    //setter and getter
    }
```

```
     import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
     import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
     import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
     import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

    @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
    class NewUseInsideMethodsTest {

    @Test
    void OldLogicTesting() throws Exception {

        StudentOldTesting oldTesting = new StudentOldTesting();
        oldTesting.setName("shraban");
        oldTesting.setId("1");
        NewUseInsideMethods insideMethods = new NewUseInsideMethods();
        StudentOldTestingReturn result = insideMethods.OldLogicTesting(oldTesting);

        Assertions.assertNotNull(result);
        Assertions.assertEquals("shraban", result.getName());
        Assertions.assertEquals("1", result.getId());

        }
       }
```

Comment: How are you computing coverage, jacoco maven plugin, some IDE built-in? To me it seems like this is the problem, not your test code.

Comment: Maven plugin . jacoco.

Comment: Then show this code, your plugin setup is probably wrong

Comment: I test in eclipse junit coverage.   it's 0% also.    Test cash is passing. green.